# Is it correct to turn "normal" parameters into templatized ones?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, parameters, parameter-passing

If the parameter of a function **will** be known at compile-time, is it *correct* to turn it into a template parameter?

Take the following code as an example:

```
template<typename ... P> void
    LOG
    ( const severity_level & l , const P & ... p )
    {
        // Take the parameters from 'p' and use it to construct a message.
        // Then, prepend a string depending on the severity level specified.
    }
```

As the severity level will always be a compile-time constant, I can do this:

```
template<severity_level L , typename ... P> void
    LOG
    ( const P & ... p )
    {
        // Call me like this:  LOG<debug>("this is a debugging message")
    }
```

With little modification to the source code, I can get rid of one parameter. Are there any drawbacks to this solution, or is it just fine?

Best regards,
Kalrish

P.S.: Another benefit of this is an easier compile-time filtering of, in this example, logging calls.

Comment: You mentioned the drawbacks yourself: 1) has to be known at compile time, 2) there is no "one function that logs" anymore. Note that of course the *call sites* will know the severity level at compile time, but the templated version prohibits writing generic code *anywhere* in the logging pipeline.

Comment: @DanielFrey You're right, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: @a.lasram It is an example enumeration. About the reference, I don't get what you mean. FWIW, I've just fixed a mistake (changed `typename L` to `severity_level L`).

Comment: Hmm, it depends on use cases :/ ... For the one you've given as example it's a bad idea IMHO (have a look @TimothyShields answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to being restricted to compile-time values, non-type template parameters are restricted to certain types: Integral, enum, pointer, lvalue reference, pointer to member, or `std::nullptr_t` types. So if a parameter isn't one of those then you can't convert it to a template parameter. Of course a severity level is probably an enum and so this is probably fine.

One thing to keep in mind is that, even if your code matches the requirements right now, in the future you might want to make changes, and it might be harder if you constrain yourself this way. For example maybe you'll eventually want to make some message log at different severity levels based on user options.

Unless you can identify a concrete benefit you should probably avoid making the change.

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine someone wanting to write code like the following.

```
severity_level level = none;
if (discrepancy > .05)
{
    level = fatal;
}
else if (discrepancy > .01)
{
    level = warning;
}

if (level != none)
{
    //Taking some liberty with the printf-like signature...
    LOG(level, "Discrepancy in thingamabob: %f", discrepancy);
}
```

So using the templated approach is a bad idea.

Comment: can be easily worked around by using function pointers ;)

Comment: @PlasmaHH "easily" haha

Comment: I have never really seen a need for this type of use. You can move the log into the if statement and then provide different infos on different severity levels.